# Laravel lazy eager loading with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using the lazy eager loading feature of Laravel's Eloquent to first query some `payments` and then eager loading the `payers` into each `payment` using `->load()`.

**For clarification:** `users hasMany payers hasAndBelongsToMany payments`

Here is the code I use (took a while to figure out but it works)

```
    //Get all the payments for the logged in user
    $payments = Payment::whereHas('payers', function($q){
        $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id); 
    },'>=', DB::raw('1'))
    ->get();


    //lazy eager load the pivot data, which contains payer info for each payment
    $payments = $payments->load(array(
        'payers' => function($q){
            $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        }));
```

Currently the query just uses `get()` to obtain the payments. If I change this to `paginate()` it works too but the lazy eager loading fails as there is no `->load()` method for pagination. This means I must always query all the payments.

How can I paginate this query?

**Edit:** table schema
[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, from my original answer, I still believe you can improve your initial query. If you have the user you wish to find all Payments for, you should be able to do so through a simple Eloquent relationship, rather than directly via the `Payment` model with a more complicated `whereHas()` statement.

Second, the `load()` method for lazy eager loading is actually attached to the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` class. This is what's missing and preventing your lazy loading from working.

If you *have* to lazy eager load (eager loading would work fine on the initial query, with or without pagination), you'll want to wrap the Paginator's items in that collection.

```
$paginator = Auth::user()->payments()->paginate(10);

$payments = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($payments->getItems());
$payments->load('payer');
```

*(Note: untested!)*

Essentially you're duplicating the items from the Paginator into its own new collection. You'll want to pass both variables to your view, assuming you want the generated page links and such as well as the loaded collection.

Paginator does have a `setItems()` method where you can overwrite the original items array, but I don't know how it will impact the rest of the Paginator methods. Use with caution.

---

*Original mistaken answer:*

It appears you're only loading payments for a single user. Why would you need to eager load each payer when there's only one person, whom you **already have** via `Auth::user()`?

Ideally, you'd have a `payments()` relationship on your `User` model, and you could simply load that user's payments via `Auth::user()->payments`.

Comment: Understood. Updated answer. You may want to rename `user_id` as it seems pretty ambiguous if two users can be assigned to a payment. `recipient_id` is more self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't think you've got it. Users is simply used for Auth. A `User` account has many `payers`. These `payers` have a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship to `payments` via a join table. I think you are right in that I can simplify my query but trying you're suggestion gives numerous errors. I've posted a visual schema in my question (excluding the users table, which should be to the left). Still learning Laravel and this is pretty complex.

Comment: Your DB structure doesn't make sense to me. You'd have to explain your app more, and that's outside of the scope of this question. Regardless, I've explained why the `load()` method is not there, and an option on how to work around that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$paginator = Auth::user()->payments()->paginate(10);

$payments = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($payments->getCollection());
$payments->load('payer');
```